# Form Optimization In AX2012/R3

Tags: optimization, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

We are using AX2012 R3 and our clients say that VendInvoiceInfoListPage form is too slowly. I checked custom development in this form, there isn't any custom development.

Our clients also say, when they are clicked NewInvoiceAction button, AX keeping them waiting.

How can i optimize this standart process? Please direct me a solution or documentation

Comment: Take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/appuser-itpro/optimize-performance

Answer (score 1):

In this case this is a specific form. So the best way to proceed is, to trace this functionality using the tracing cockpit (it's in the Tools menu when you start the Developer window (Ctrl+D). Make sure you create the trace on the AOS server, with the client started in Administrator mode.

Start the tracing cockpit, and then open the Vendor invoices list page form. This will generate a (large) trace file, which you can import in the AX 2012 Trace Parser. This Trace parser will show you exactly which code or SQL call is running slow.

Most of the time performance can be improved by cleaning/archiving data or improving indexing of the table.